# Binary Comparison .NET Assembly - Ignore Version and Timestamp

Tags: c#

I need to compare two .NET Binaries from two different Builds.
However the Binaries currently always differ because at least the Version as well as the Timestamp is different.
Is there a way to determine if the assemblies have been build from the same commit?

Comment: i suppose you could `IL disassemble` both and compare that way

Comment: If your build is set to compile with [`-deterministic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/deterministic-compiler-option) then the binaries should be bit-identical. Otherwise there will be several other differences besides version and timestamp.

Comment: Thank you - will try both. The -deterministic parameter looks quite promising.
I am not sure about IL disassemble since it says: Currently, you cannot use this technique with PE files that contain embedded native code (for example, PE files produced by Visual C++).. I am not sure if this is a blocker for me.